# Swift: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift

```
var session = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("session")!
println(session)
```

I am getting crash with following error:

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Why it is downvoted ?

Comment: There are 430 search results for `[swift] "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"` and 6 results for `[swift] NSUserDefaults "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"` – Are you sure that none of them solves your problem?

Comment: @MartinR Yeah I saw few search results and everyone has posted entire source code. Being a fresher its impossible to go through hundreds of line of code to figure out my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're getting crash due to the forced unwrapping operator ! which is attempting to force unwrap a value from a nil optional.

The forced unwrapping operator should be used only when an optional is known to contain a non-nil value.

You can use `optional binding:`

```
if let session = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("session") {
    printString(session)
}
```

Comment: Downvoters, care to comment. Whats wrong with the solution? Being a 6 years of active member on stackoverflow I know its so easy to click downvote button,  but don't ever to do that without proper comments.

Comment: For your comment and answer you get one UPvote - I agree, people are here to learn, and noobs (like myself) get put off when people downvote. We just need a little guidance is all..

Answer (score 8):

you should use the [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) "??"

```
let session = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("session") ?? ""
```

**Xcode 8.2 • Swift 3.0.2**

```
let session = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "session") ?? ""
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `!` at the end or you need to check before you unwrap if like this:

If there is a value at that location put in the session constant and execute the block of the `if`, if not skip the `if` block

```
if let session = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("session") {
    println(session)
}
```

You should take a look over the Swift documentation regarding `Optional` type [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330)