# prepare segue unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Yes, *another* found nil while unwrapping an Optional value error. I have read tons of other stack overflow posts with similar errors such as  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500336/swift-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value)  one and many others. I still do not fully understand how to properly deal with unwrapping a variable.

I have a class that is similar to the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField?
@IBOutlet weak var valueInput: UITextField?

var checkbox : CheckBox?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let name = nameTextField.text ?? ""
    let state = buttonState.getIsChecked()
    let value : Int? = Int(valueInput.text!)
    let isMoveable = true

    checkbox = CheckBox(name: name, value: value, state: state, isMoveable: isMoveable)
}
```

I get the error on the line the "let value : Int? = Int(valueInput.text!) line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sahil's answer is on track, but doesn't address that `valueInput` is also an optional. Use this code:

```
if let valueInput = valueInput,
    let val = valueInput.text {
    value = Int(val)
}
```

In addition regarding  properly unwrapping the optional `valueInput` I wanted to add that chances are that if `valueInput` is an `IBOutlet` it's defined as:

```
@IBOutlet weak var valueInput: UITextField!
```

That's called an implicitly unwrapped optional. The annoying thing is that since it is also an `IBOutlet`, if it ever becomes disconnected from the `UITextField` in Interface Builder, the variable will become nil, and accessing it from anywhere in the code will cause a crash.

Change it to this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var valueInput: UITextField?
```

I've also written about this on my blog: http://cleanswifter.com/implicitly-unwrapped-iboutlets/

Note: you didn't show the definition of `valueInput` so I assumed it to be a `UITextField`

Comment: Yes, that was part of the problem! I'll edit the code in my question

Comment: Ok great, so did it fix the problem?

Comment: yup! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can safely unwrap the value using `if let` construct

```
var value : Int? = nil 

if let val = valueInput.text {
  value = Int(val) // it would either nil or optional value
}
```

and also you can do it by [nil coalescing operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html) `??` in  a single line

```
let value : Int? = Int(valueInput.text ?? "")
```

**UPDATE**

First check if textfields disconnected from the Interface Builder , if not connect, connect them. and if you become your textfields optionals you also have to safely unwrap the textfields ( you forgot to  add  it from interface builder and it will not crash if you make them optionals).

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

var name: String? = nil
var value : Int? = nil
let state = buttonState.getIsChecked()
let isMoveable = true


if let nameTextField = self.nameTextField where nameTextField.text != nil {
  name = nameTextField.text!
}

if let valueTextField = self.valueInput where valueTextField.text != nil {
  value = Int(valueTextField.text!)
}

 checkbox = CheckBox(name: name, value: value, state: state, isMoveable: isMoveable)

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! I still get the error, though

Comment: for the if let, the error occurs on the 'if let val = valueInput.text' line. It also occurs on the nil coalescing operator line

Comment: See my answer, `valueInput` is the optional that is nil, NOT valueInput.text

Comment: okay. seems like  your textfields disconnected from the Interface Builder (connect them)and if your nameTextField and valueInput is optionals. you also have to first do the optional binding.  i will update the answer